# What's wrong with display on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So i have problem with a different display website on PC and mobile phone.
My viewport looks so:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

`window.innerWidth` on my Samsung Galaxy returns '360', but:

so looks element in google chrome device mode
[image: so looks element in google chrome device mode]

but that's how looks it actually on my device
[image: but that's how looks it actually on my device]

So what's the matter?

Comment: You a missing a comma before `maximum-scale`.

Comment: Stupid mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add comma before maximum-scale

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```